# Oracle SQL Developer Recent file list

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer is there a way to view the most recent files I've had open? This would be similiar to Word, Excel or even SQL Server Mgmt Studio has a list of the last 5 or 10 SQL files that you opened.

Answer (score 9):

just use the shortcut Ctrl+equals.
By default this shows only the **open** documents, but you can see all the recent files (including closed ones) by checking the **show all** checkbox.

Answer (score 7):

Try Navigate->Go To Recent Files